# Take a Ten Minute Walk: A City Tour Solution

Tags: javascript

I recently came across the following problem on Codewars:

> ## [Take a Ten Minute Walk](https://www.codewars.com/kata/take-a-ten-minute-walk)
>
> You live in the city of Cartesia where all roads are laid out in a perfect grid.
>   You arrived ten minutes too early to an appointment, so you decided to take 
>   the opportunity to go for a short walk. The city provides its citizens with a 
>   Walk Generating App on their phones -- every time you press the button it sends you an array of one-letter strings representing directions to walk 
>   (eg. ['n', 's', 'w', 'e']).
>   You know it takes you one minute to traverse one city block, so create a function 
>   that will return true if the walk the app gives you will take you exactly ten
>    minutes (you don't want to be early or late!) and will, of course, return you to 
>   your starting point. Return `false` otherwise.

I solved the problem with the following function:

```
function isValidWalk(walk) {
  var directions = {
    'n': 0,
    's': 0,
    'e': 0,
    'w': 0
  }
  walk.forEach( function(direction) {
    directions[direction]++;
  }
  var displacement = {
    x: directions['n'] - directions['s'],
    y: directions['e'] - directions['w']
  }
  /*it take 1 min to traverse 1 block & I only have 10 minutes, 
  & I also want to attend appointment, so i want to come from where i start.*/
  return walk.length === 10 && displacement.x === 0 && displacement.y === 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var directions = {
  'n': 0,
  's': 0,
  'e': 0,
  'w': 0
}
```

Quotes are optional on all valid property names.

```
walk.forEach( function(direction) {
  directions[direction]++;
}
```

Syntax error here. Plus, making whitespaces consistent would make this code less of an eye sore. Consider using an IDE that will yell at you for inconsistent formatting.

```
var displacement = {
  x: directions['n'] - directions['s'],
  y: directions['e'] - directions['w']
}
```

Storing in an object is unnecessary. `x` and `y` can just be variables here.

---

An alternate approach is to represent the directions into 2 columns, vertical and horizontal. Then the directions on the same axis are represented `1` and `-1`. This way, knowing if you're back is a matter of checking if both axes sum up to zero. No subtraction required.

```
   V  H
N  1  0
S -1  0 
E  0  1
E  0  1
W  0 -1
Result: [0, 1] 
// Off by 1 to the east. Also, length is less than 10.
```

This is also a good functional programming exercise on how to think of functions as data transformations instead of machine commands. In the following code, each array method transforms the data from directions to a boolean in three discrete steps.

```js
const directionVector = {
  N: [1, 0],
  S: [-1, 0],
  E: [0, 1],
  W: [0, -1]
}

const isValidWalk = walk => walk.length === 10 && walk
  .map(direction => directionVector[direction])
  .reduce((prev, next) => [prev[0] + next[0], prev[1] + next[1]], [0, 0])
  .every(v => v === 0)

// length check goes first so code doesn't even try if it's not 10
// map converts direction into vectors: N -> [V, H]
// reduce sums all vectors: [V1, H1] + [V2, H2] + ... = [Vs, Hs]
// every checks if sum values are all zero: Vs === 0, Hs === 0

// Too short
console.log(isValidWalk(['N', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'W', 'E']))

// Too long
console.log(isValidWalk(['N', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'N', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'N', 'S', 'E']))

// We're back!
console.log(isValidWalk(['N', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'N', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'N', 'S']))

// We're lost
console.log(isValidWalk(['N', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'N', 'S', 'E', 'W', 'N', 'E']))
```

Answer (score 1):

All in all I think, your solution is rather elegant. A tiny improvement could be:

```
function isValidWalk(walk) {
  var directions = {
    N: 0,
    S: 0,
    E: 0,
    W: 0
  };

  walk.forEach(function (direction) {
    directions[direction]++;
  });

  var isHome = () => {
    return directions['N'] == directions['S'] && directions['E'] == directions['W'];
  }
  /*it take 1 min to traverse 1 block & I only have 10 minutes,
  & I also want to attend appointment, so i want to come from where i start.*/
  return walk.length === 10 && isHome();
}
```

The only caveat is (as others have pointed out) that you don't check the `walk.length` before you start walking.

That could be solved by using `array.reduce` in a way like this:

```
function isValidWalk(directions) {
  var isHome = (offsets) => {
    return offsets['N'] == offsets['S'] && offsets['E'] == offsets['W'];
  }

  var walk = (offsets, dir) => {
    offsets[dir]++;
    return offsets;
  }

  return directions.length === 10 && isHome(directions.reduce(walk, { N: 0, S: 0, E: 0, W: 0 }));
}
```